# how to write a Withdraw function from my contract contract

Tags: solidity

So I am new to solidity and I want to add a withdraw function to the attached smart contract so that when i call the withdraw function it will give me Eth / token in the contract.

[Link to smart contract code](https://pastebin.com/bxESAUwm)

Comment: have you made any progress?